# debugging not working in physical device. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, adb

When I was trying to debug my app in physical device getting error as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: en-AE=https://www.gstatic.com/android-search/hotword/x_google/9b74550b2fb24680fdac9ec59c56e828/hotword.data and en-AE=https://www.gstatic.com/android-search/hotword/x_google/9b74550b2fb24680fdac9ec59c56e828/hotword.data
```

[image]